# Shapefile has feature that I cannot edit on QGIS 3.10.13 on Windows 10

Tags: qgis, layers, editing, rendering, transparency-opacity

I am editing a map with multiple layers. The project includes a shapefile for buildings that has numerous rectangles in black with 100% transparency as a single symbol, The layer file is at the top of the list but one other layers in the project has various polygons in  Catorgarized colors at 50% transparency. These do not let the black show through.

There are other layers with polygons of categorized colors that overlay the same black shapefile and these do not cover the black. I have tried redrawing parts of both layers but the issue persists.

I have limited knowledge of QGIS. I am trying to produce a Layout for printing . As part of this I am moving features ie Buildings on a layer and adding text to some items. I am using the vertex tool. I have done several layouts with other layers without a problem but this one layer covers the features on my building layer.

[image: Screen Dump]

I think me saying edit is not helpful. If you look at the screen shot you can see the rectangles are showing dark green. They should be black. The rectangles are in the Building layer which is at the top of the layer panel. Why does the green feature which is in another layer cover the building layer. How can I change it?

I understand the operations available but unfortunately it does not change the map. I have deleted items on the layer and redrawn them but they are still covered by the other layer. I have shut down and reloaded twice.

You will not believe this I have just gone to the layers to do a screen dump and the buildings are now showing. I didn't change anything.

Comment: Please include more information: How do you try to edit the Shapefile? You want to change the geometry or the attributes? Can you add a screenshot showing the layer and how you try to edit? Without further information, it's almost impossible to guess what could be wrong.

Comment: One question per post, please. See the [tour] about how this side works. So you want to change the style (appearance) of the black building polygons, right? Click of the layer in the layer panel (on the left) to select it. Than Open the Layer Styling panel, where you can change the transparency of the layer. Also check in no layer blending mode is active. If you include another screenshot, please make it bigger so that details can be seen.

Comment: Unfortunately, as long as we don't see how the Layer Styling panel of the layer in discussion looks like, it is difficult to say where the problem is. Please add information, otherwise the question risks to be closed.

Comment: You may also check in the "layer order" panel that your building are indeed on top

Comment: @J. R:: according to the updated question, the OP states that the problem has been solved (see last sentence). So we will never know the reason that caused the problem.